# UIBarButtonItem with "More" button style

Tags: ios, button, coding-style, toolbar

I am trying to create a table search with a search bar similar to [this](http://appcubby.com/gas/manual_assets/search.png), where the "More" button will take you to the advanced search page.  I have the search bar embedded in a toolbar, and a button to the right of it, but the UIBarButtonItem does not have the "More" style, it seems reserved for UITabBarItems.

Is there a way I can get some kind of system image for this and construct it that way, or do I have to create my own "More" image and apply it to the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html), the more button item is not an available item for you to use. You will have to create your own bar button image.

Comment: Yeah saw the docs and saw that it wasnt an available style for a UIBarButtonItem, are those icons available somewhere hidden deep within the iphone framework for us to get at at all?

Comment: Not from within your sandbox.

Comment: So the official answer is, I don't have access to it, and need to create my own image, thanks